# How to change the color of a svg?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Created a svg using figma and am attempting to change the color in css. fill: black is not working.

SVG Code:

```
<svg width="58" height="57" viewBox="0 0 58 57" version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<title>track</title>
<desc>Created using Figma</desc>
<g id="Canvas" transform="translate(-12596 1455)">
<g id="track">
<use xlink:href="#path0_fill" fill="url(#pattern0)" 
transform="translate(12596 -1455)"/>
</g>
</g>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0" transform="matrix(0.0172414 0 0 0.0175439 0 0)"/>
</pattern>
<path id="path0_fill" d="M 0 0L 58 0L 58 57L 0 57L 0 0Z"/>
<image id="image0" width="58" height="57" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your SVG code does not contain fill: black or any inclusion of any CSS file either.

Comment: The css file is included in the head of the html document

Comment: CSS does not cross document boundaries. You must directly include it in the document that you want it to apply to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution `CSS` + `SVG`

In the first answer was a solution purely with the help of SVG.
If you want to control the coloring of an image from an **external style sheet**, you must specify the path to this stylesheet in the first line of the svg file.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
```

where you must specify the full path to your style sheet.

- The color of the image lines will produce a filter:

  `#image0 {
  filter:url(#WhiteFilter);
  }`
- Coloring the background of images

  `#path0_fill {
  fill:black;
  }`

*Below is the full code:*

```css
svg path {
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
}
#path0_fill {
fill:black;
}
#image0 {
filter:url(#WhiteFilter);
}
```

```html
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?> 
<svg width="58" height="57" viewBox="0 0 58 57" version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >


 <defs>
 <!-- black filter  -->
 <filter id="BlackFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="75" height="75">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
 
 <!-- white filter  -->
 <filter id="WhiteFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="75" height="75">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="1 0 0 0 0
                        0 1 0 0 0
                        0 0 1 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
 
 </defs>


<path id="path0_fill" d="M 0 0L 58 0L 58 57L 0 57L 0 0Z" />

<image id="image0" width="58" height="57" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADoAAAA5CAYAAABnLziGAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAA2xpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuNi1jMTM4IDc5LjE1OTgyNCwgMjAxNi8wOS8xNC0wMTowOTowMSAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wTU09Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9tbS8iIHhtbG5zOnN0UmVmPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvc1R5cGUvUmVzb3VyY2VSZWYjIiB4bWxuczp4bXA9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC8iIHhtcE1NOk9yaWdpbmFsRG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDo2NEU2MTVDOEVCQzJFNzExOEZEREJDOEMwMDc0QjFGOCIgeG1wTU06RG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDo0NkI1NEZDMEVBRUUxMUU3OUNDQURGQjhFQzQwNTExNSIgeG1wTU06SW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDo0NkI1NEZCRkVBRUUxMUU3OUNDQURGQjhFQzQwNTExNSIgeG1wOkNyZWF0b3JUb29sPSJBZG9iZSBQaG90b3Nob3AgQ0MgMjAxNyAoTWFjaW50b3NoKSI+IDx4bXBNTTpEZXJpdmVkRnJvbSBzdFJlZjppbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOjgzNjI4N0NBMDFERkU3MTFBNjFFQzgyMkEyM0JDMTdBIiBzdFJlZjpkb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOjY0RTYxNUM4RUJDMkU3MTE4RkREQkM4QzAwNzRCMUY4Ii8+IDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPiA8L3JkZjpSREY+IDwveDp4bXBtZXRhPiA8P3hwYWNrZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+Ui8d1QAABstJREFUeNrcm3ts11QUx7v+tgFjGwPHwMxJiIKvRdGJGB+bYwka0MwHJAZNiJCJwRiZmUHjgixGjAkRIyj/iEIgU4KZ2UCyQIRoJj5BIyEyifKQZey9wfjNPX6/eo5+m5zUtr+2v3Yr3OST9dfe23tP7+m555zbpWiapgRQHiEKiTwijWgjzhL1RK8yFoUF9YkbiV1ENxHXzEs/0UQs9LFfR6T4NKOfEEuIiDgXJ4b5WWJWI4Y2PxOPEWdGY0KTFbSAaCKu1RWE+JWoJRqITgh8FXEn8QxRTIxD/SjxBNEYZtWdRnQJtTxFlDloN5P4UrQbIRYErbrJND4hBtvoof3r4l2OEgVBCqp6VIQ3iBtw/DXxkIu2FVDvvcRanJtA7A6b6qbDenLpxG+nbZ+DqnI5jHMHhWaUhEl1K8XAKgzXWP2+IjYlEHKQeFy0GcT5A2ES9AcMqsvk2qviIexwIKRimNX+sAiqEhcxqN0m12cQ7ULYbcQqg5CLTdqtxHU2TnPDIGgmEcOgKi3qXE10mHhFLOQSizYzxMNYFQarywt/Co6tfNZWYg6cBb0MEU/ZWFb2hWOiD9+LW0FHxHGqTb0WCHueGICQnznsIxaEoKku63dhINwuP0HdFriIOYbZNSs3wR9WEOWM+Yz+DWEVh07CiAMhuZTjlWC/+JswCMrlCP7eSuT6NI4nhcacCoug7wu37U0fxsCzORvHdWEL084gNGNrWkoc9th/BvEHMR2xawEs8KjO6HgiXSAN10rEnnx+jwPDZFUOQkguHwghU3HvbCLTMA4jnp36Mrh3HDpdAlG4Z9tFva3CGehy6ZBPIY6K9s3i2ib0xX0OwdG4ZII+vr1OAguzk/WademHG6jX3SeuDUP4fJsOxxPVRJ9o9xeRLeq0a+7LIi85o8+JR3F8HAt+BEvFFuJjQ/0PieXCYxokjhHfYqmIYZ0sI27DuioteDFSKnrh3NNqYhYxFeeaiR7xqsWh1jfj9wFigVvVrcNTYp82w6EqlhInXcwAq3pVgnvWCEd/jkWds6jDKp6TjK871eGrfggzMJ/4gjgHTYgDts4dxHfIMLA/uyHBPSeK48kWdTbjL3tV1W5ntF7M6MwkIoZstJ9F5Hlo/46Y0VKLOhki29HtdkZbhXN9MYml6wK8nJNEe0B+QFQ4GTzrS92so9UwMCsc+qljXWpExPOaG0E78R7tCJEwgzbX2LP6SURBt1uFaVOIe00Ejzt4OHq00R3kbgKy/AOGvlUsf1H43A2ouw7+8/+MUaeWXLmA9Inf6Y/Noo+4BX0wdly/VRjR1WbGaGKSTzwD/miQSYEUC7KIa1DnPTHTG+Gw5MmbPYCNnpi4qelKZOhYgce0D5bV79IvjuuQsZD9R7DBdQjn3iKmEc9DrruJ0zBQG5XR3qd0wQahtoUu2hURvxter5pUw8u9AsYplmAW+4htSK0EVVQPHpruP8+G5/UiZvcVKeguYrGLGz4MwlqqkJLlDbF01eFaZVaGLgNnotnMsj1N7MQLLddJYxwXwbq5ZxQH7HV7c5xVXrcxpDOjBnEDFr6SuEe5gopZpn4d1p4okl69YzS2uAN3NKkZLRR528khmRCvgqbYCTos1tD4Za6xqtOXvG0MBzkgjrs83qPX7h2VD6EJWfkRwzKjIRjIE/mgmI0GRHC/uGK9LaiiXhwe111C/d5FHioNvzUEE7mwJR1op4p78Zivs9uSkOnOK9rqfkosFOl+DbOgf9NnZiSMwXjMJgryYkw0k/6lDYlY9K9HOZabTKwSJ5CWPI2QpwJ+I5c/iZfhQLOQzxIv4eFwonmeIcxKZiL0jyfXIgTj8j2xBuNQkfB+AUJxcq8I9TjTsMUq3alzHiHOcfw+h9+tFvWXibCoKoCwTd/GOObg+yf9y5cS/YTdtmE7wiO2fj8S90MV3uawx6JNJ7SgD8lq1YdZ1bCez8Vv/h6i1ibFmgVf/Bflv63N651YXd1xKBbnexKYcxZ0EvFgADaFhT6aIFuYhZh6fiJjpJdavJcqZjJNJIqtyiQxoCEL46KJv4rDOhGMlc/dAfthF63oS5RukNoS7XjnwMBMQGqR107+amSGSd1yLE184+0IfP1QXR70dMxkGv4WmdTjj563on/OH61H/+q/mubCGKwXL/sR4j5s6ObD+AyIb29zAzBGH4n+9yOPlIlU6xrRfw/2YZP6RK7JkGsdwJadJnKqSwNKlvEG9G+GvvrFl6H69mGJX1931orv9mThRHh5wJnBdHztHTPpv4WY5/d/SfCXKMuxz8E7bvuRNB6t2HURsYy4BQ5/A/zhEasG/wgwAPFlXvD3qCe+AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" />

</svg>
```

**Update**

Adding as a result of the comment:

- line image machine in your example draws a `filter`
- `path` in your example draws a border around the image of the
  machine, so there was no background write in CSS

`#path0_fill {
fill:none;
stroke:black;`

```css
svg path {
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
}
#path0_fill {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:2px;
}
#image0 {
filter:url(#BlackFilter);
}
```

```html
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?> 
<svg width="58" height="57" viewBox="0 0 58 57" version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >


 <defs>
 <!-- black filter  -->
 <filter id="BlackFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="75" height="75">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
 
 <!-- white filter  -->
 <filter id="WhiteFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="75" height="75">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="1 0 0 0 0
                        0 1 0 0 0
                        0 0 1 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
 
 </defs>


<path id="path0_fill" d="M 0 0L 58 0L 58 57L 0 57L 0 0Z" />

<image id="image0" width="58" height="57" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" />

</svg>
```

Comment: This solution works, but how can i change the color of the svg lines, not the background? Using the fill property on the path only changes the color of the background.

Comment: @KevinMangal  Adding as a result of the comment.  See the updated example

Comment: @KevinMangal Your machine is painted in base64 format, so it can not be colored by the usual methods: `fill`, `stroke`

Answer (score 1):

### Solution  SVG

The image in base64 format can not be stylized in the usual ways:

- neither in the external stylesheet css `fill:black;`
- nor with the presentation styles SVG `fill="black"`

But with the help of [SVG filters](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters) you can paint the image in any color

There is a very [useful article](http://alistapart.com/article/finessing-fecolormatrix), in my opinion, on the use of filters for coloring images.

*Filter for painting in black color of lines:*

```
<!-- black filter  -->
 <filter id="BlackFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="75" height="75">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
```

in the examples below `path` Is responsible for coloring the background

```
<path id="path0_fill" d="M 0 0L 58 0L 58 57L 0 57L 0 0Z" fill="white"/>
```

Unfortunately from the question I did not understand what you want to paint in black: the background or the outline of the image, so I'll give two options.

**#1 white background, black lines**

```html
<svg width="58" height="57" viewBox="0 0 58 57" version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >


 <defs>
 <!-- black filter  -->
 <filter id="BlackFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="75" height="75">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
          
 </defs>


<path id="path0_fill" d="M 0 0L 58 0L 58 57L 0 57L 0 0Z" fill="white"/>

<image id="image0" width="58" height="57" filter="url(#BlackFilter)"  preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" />

</svg>
```

**#2 black background, white lines**

```html
<svg width="58" height="57" viewBox="0 0 58 57" version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >


 <defs>
  <!-- white filter  -->
 <filter id="WhiteFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="75" height="75">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="1 0 0 0 0
                        0 1 0 0 0
                        0 0 1 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
 </defs>

<path id="path0_fill" d="M 0 0L 58 0L 58 57L 0 57L 0 0Z" fill="black"/>

<image id="image0" width="58" height="57" preserveAspectRatio="none" filter="url(#WhiteFilter)" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" />

</svg>
```

Comment: These work, but how can i change the color of the svg lines, not the background? In both cases using the fill property on the path only changes the color of the background.