# How to change the color of an SVG icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

For the following svg the fill css property changes the color of the background of the svg, but not the actual svg icon.

```
<svg width="58" height="57" viewBox="0 0 58 57" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
    <!-- white filter  -->
 <filter id="WhiteFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="75" height="75">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="1 0 0 0 0
                        0 1 0 0 0
                        0 0 1 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
    </defs>
<path id="path0_fill" class="colorFill" d="M 0 0L 58 0L 58 57L 0 57L 0 0Z"/>
<image id="image3" width="58" height="57" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
</svg>
```

I am targeting the path in the css file

```
#path0_fill{
    fill: green;
}
```

How can I make it so that the color of the svg icon changes, and not the background?

Comment: A vector graphic with an image element is just a bad wrapper for a rasterized image. You are not going to have any luck with this particular svg file.

Comment: Even though the truck logo isn't an SVG path, there is a way to color it (using an SVG filter on the `<image>` element). In fact, @Alexandr_T showed you how to do it in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48298058/1869660

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the color of an image that way. If you load SVG as an image, you can't change how it is displayed using CSS or Javascript in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using SVG editor like Inkscape and use "Fill Bounded Area" tool to fill the green color.
Please find your updated logo here:
[Your Logo](http://www.simplygoodtoshare.com/SVG/Logo.svg)

Answer (score 0):

The path you are targeting just forms the rectangle (in the background.

If you are trying to change the white outline parts of the icon, then you are pretty much out of luck.  That is because those parts are in the form of a raster bitmap.  There is currently no real way to re-colour a bitmap with CSS.  Not in an SVG anyway.

Although you icon is technically an SVG file, it isn't a very good one.  As @JasonB says, it's really just an SVG wrapper around a PNG image.  You are not getting any of the benefit of SVGs vector capabilities, such as being able to scale smoothly to any size.

To do what you want to do, you should load your SVG into a vector editor (like Inkscape, Illustrator, Sketch etc) and replace the PNG image with an actual vector elements such as a `<path>`.